# Talend ESB Database synchronization

Tags: database, synchronization, soa, esb, talend

I'm trying to implement an ESB in order to connect two different applications. I need to synchronize their databases, which means that once there is a change in the first database, it should be automatically reflected on the second database at the same time.

The first application (Java EE/Hibernate) has an Oracle database and the second one (PHP/Symfony2) has a MySQL DB. I'm working with Talend Open Studio for ESB V5.2.

I really need some help here especially that I'm new to this ESB thing.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community. Before posting, please be sure to read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. I don't see any real question here.

Answer (score -2):

To get some help on Talend Open Studio for ESB, you might want to go to tutorial pages on the TalendForge and check the Application Integration tutorials. They should help you: http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/menu.php

Best,
Talend Data.